# Wordpress Media Library - Upload space used

Tags: uploads, limit

Navigating to Media -> Library, I don't get the upload space used displayed:

[image]

as I should based on various screenshots on the net:

[image]

Im using WordPress 4.2.6 and Im self-hosted on a shared hosting plan.

Is it possible to display this kind of stats?

Comment: If I am correct this is shown for `wordpress.com` users. Maybe you make a `function` with help from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_space_used) or [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/display_space_usage)?

Comment: That is indeed only shown on sites hosted with wordpress.com. That is not part of WordPress core

Comment: Ok so I guess there's a different way to get these kind of stats to site admins depending on the hosting provider? I wouldn't like giving them access to Plesk...

Comment: @LePhleg, sorry for late responding, maybe [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-quota-per-user/) helps you out?